# How can a 16bit data line from a CPU access data from a 8bit data line from RAM?

Tags: cpu, ram, digital-logic

I have the following case, where a CPU with 16bit (d0-d15) data line and i want to connect it to a 8bit (d0-d7) data line of a RAM for read and write. I can connect the first d0-d7 to each other, but the CPU still have another d8-d15 left over, i am sure i can utilize this extra data line to read more information from the RAM than just 8bits at a time. But I am not sure how the connections would be.

Here is the diagram:

[image]

I am not sure how the RAM would looks if i connect the extra d8-d15 lines to RAM? do i connect using a multiplexer to decide when to select the data from which 8bit line?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer hardware design, not software

Comment: (Typically, I'd expect to see a second ram module hooked up with exactly the same non-data connections)

Answer (score 2):

If the CPU asks for 16 bits, then the RAM needs to accept and deliver 16 bits in parallel, so you'd need logic to create a second RAM access. For a simple design, that is not worthwhile.

Your options are:

1. Use 16 bit RAM.
2. Use two 8 bit RAMs in parallel.
3. Find out if the CPU can be instructed to generate two 8 bit accesses for every 16 bit access.

If the CPU has an A0 address line, there is actually a chance that it does support generating 8 bit wide accesses, as you wouldn't need it if all accesses are on word boundaries anyway.

Note that this will be slower than just using 16 bit accesses.

Comment: so I can have two 8bit ram and use a0 from cpu to select which ram i am reading from? thus i can read 8bits from ram1 and another 8bits from ram2?

Also I read about addressing the lower part of memory and higher part of memory to read 8bits from each (low and high) to obtain 16bits. I don't quite understand that

Comment: How that is done precisely depends on the CPU. The Motorola 68000 for example assumes that data read from even addresses is on D8-D15, even if it performed a byte access -- then A0 can be effectively ignored. Other CPUs may require word data on D0-D15, and byte data on D0-D7, so when reading a byte from an even address, you need to shift the data.